# Запятая в воскрицании "Так(,) да!"

Tags: пунктуация

Когда хочешь что-то эмоционально подтвердить, с чем-то согласиться, говоришь "Так(,) да!" Но вот я всегда торможу: нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "так" здесь выступает в роли усилительной частицы запятая не нужна.

*- Чай будешь?

 - Так да! Конечно буду.*

Если в роли местоимения, то запятая требуется.

*- Так нужно делать?

- Так, да. Всё правильно*

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что запятую здесь можно определить по ударению. Сравните:

ТАк, да! Так дА!